# Complete topological groups in which all subgroups are closed

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups, topological-vector-spaces

My [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/377972/2106) has been [answered by YCor](https://mathoverflow.net/a/377975/14094); so I am asking a new one with a reasonable additional assumption. See the previous question for the background and motivation.

General question: does there exist a complete, nondiscrete topological group $G$ such that all subgroups of $G$ are closed? Or, does there exist a complete, nondiscrete topological vector space $V$ such that all vector subspaces of $V$ are closed?

More specific question: does there exist a complete, nondiscrete topological abelian group $A$ with linear topology such that all subgroups of $A$ are closed? Or, does there exist a complete, nondiscrete topological vector space $V$ with linear topology such that all vector subspaces of $V$ are closed?

---

Let me collect here the less obvious definitions appearing in the questions above.  A topological abelian group $A$ is said to have *linear topology* if the open subgroups form a base of neighborhoods of zero in $A$. A topological vector space $V$ is said to have *linear topology* if open vector subspaces form a base of neighborhoods of zero in $V$.  The notion of a topological vector space with linear topology presumes that the topology on the ground field $k$ is discrete.

I define completeness in the case of a linear topology only, as the general case is more involved.  A topological abelian group $A$ with linear topology is said to be (Hausdorff and) *complete* if the natural map $A\longrightarrow \varprojlim_{U\subset A}A/U$ is bijective.  Here the projective limit is taken over all the open subgroups $U\subset A$.  For topological vector spaces with linear topology, the definition of completeness is similar.

Comment: For a Hausdorff abelian topological group, is complete the same as: for every net $(x_i)$ such that $x_i-x_j$ tends to $0$ when both $i,j$ tend to infinity, the net $(x_i)$ is convergent?

Comment: I edited in a link to @YCor's comments answering the question because, somehow, their [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/377975) was not showing up for me.  To avoid bumping, I won't edit again, but please feel free to correct my edit if you like.

Comment: @YCor Yes, I think this is a correct definition.  Alternatively, one can define the uniform structure associated with a group topology, and define what it means for a uniform space to be complete.  These should be equivalent definitions.

Comment: Sure; in non-abelian groups there are some more subtleties about completeness, but the abelian case seems the main focus here.

Comment: @YCor's definition *is* the definition of completeness under a uniformity.  Under the projective-limit definition, the limit of the Cauchy net $(x_i)$ is $(x_{i(U)})_U$, where $i(U)$ is any element such that $j \ge i(U) \implies x_{i(U)} - x_j \in U$.  Alternatively, under the uniform-completeness definition, any element $(x_U)_U$ of the projective limit *is* a Cauchy net in $A$, and so has as a lift in $A$ its limit.

Comment: Just a remark: it can't be a Polish abelian group. For a nondiscrete Polish abelian group has cardinal $c$, but always has $2^c$ subgroups, while it has only $c$ closed subsets.