# Groups with no (proper) closed subgroups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, topological-groups

$\mathbf{Z}$ with the profinite topology has the property that *every subgroup is closed* ([Topological groups in which all subgroups are closed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377972/topological-groups-in-which-all-subgroups-are-closed)). What topological groups have the property that *no (proper) subgroup is closed*?

Comment: I suppose the trivial subgroup is always closed ...

Comment: Let $S^1=\{e^{it}\mid t\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Let $x\in S^1$ be transcendental. Let $A$ be the group generated by $x$. Then $A$ has the subgroup topology inherited from $S^1$. Then every subgroup of $A$ with more than one element is dense in $S^1$, so $A$ has no non-trivial proper closed subgroup.

Comment: @JosephVanName Thanks! Nice example! Can we characterize the topological groups with these properties?

Answer (score 9):

The only discrete groups without any non-trivial proper closed subgroups are the cyclic groups of prime order. For the non-discrete case, we have a characterization of such subgroups.

Theorem: Let $G$ be a Hausdorff non-discrete topological group. Then $G$ has no proper non-trivial closed subgroup if and only if $G$ has no proper open subgroup and $G$ has no nowhere dense subgroup with more than one element.

Proof: $\rightarrow$ Every open subgroup of $G$ is automatically closed, and since $G$ is non-discrete, these clopen subgroups always have more than one element. If $G$ has a nowhere dense subgroup $H$, then $\overline{H}$ is a closed proper non-trivial subgroup of $G$.

$\leftarrow$ Suppose now that $G$ has no nowhere dense subgroup with more than one element and $G$ has no proper open subgroup. Let $H$ be a closed subgroup of $G$ with more than one element. Then since $H$ is not nowhere dense, $H^\circ$ is non-empty. Let $U$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $H^\circ$. Then $U$ is an open subgroup of $G$, but since we assumed that $G$ has no proper open subgroup, we must conclude that $G=U\subseteq H$, so $G=H$. Q.E.D.

Even though we did not assume any abelianness in the group $G$, any group $G$ with no proper non-trivial closed subgroup is necessarily abelian.

Comment: Next: non-discrete groups.